# Date of Birth Validation not working in JSP

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have created a validation to check whether there is any value entered in BirthDate or not and if there isn't any then it will show a message to *enter date of Birth*.
But it's neither working nor the alert message shows.

```js
var BirthDate=document.getElementById("dob").value;

if(dob =! ""){
        document.getElementById("dateerror").innerHTML="";
        
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("dateerror").innerHTML="**Enter date of Birth";
    }
```

```html
<label>BirthDate: </label>
<input type="date" id="dob">
<span id="dateerror"></span><br><br>
```

Comment: `var BirthDate=... ; if (dob ...)` ?

Comment: What does JSP have to do with this? The only code you've provided is HTML and JS.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one:

```
var BirthDate=document.getElementById("dob").value;

if(BirthDate=! ""){
        document.getElementById("dateerror").innerHTML="";
        
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("dateerror").innerHTML="**Enter date of Birth";
    }
```

Looks like not referring correct variable (referring dob instead of BirthDate).

Answer (score -1):

Also this is another of your faulty lines :
if(dob =! ""){

It is a syntax error and should be :

```
                    var BirthDate=document.getElementById("dob").value;
                    if (BirthDate != "")
                    {
                     document.getElementById("dateerror").innerHTML="";
                    }
                    else
                    {
              document.getElementById("dateerror").innerHTML="**Enter date of 
                Birth";
                    }
```

Comment: You need to be consistent.